# search string and and convert to byte c#

Tags: java, c#

I want to get specific string from txt file and after that convert the string to byte for example I have this txt file:

; "one"

id_number:*=344E6F4D6F7265486178785454332100

; "two"

id_number:*=3536336A775E3825246E773543563437

; "three"

id:_number*=BDBD2EB72D82473DBE09F1B552A8983

Now what I want is to search the title and after that gets the id_number of the title and after that convert it to a byte like that this for title:

TWO (
 byte[] two = new byte[] { 0xBD, 0xBD, 0x2E, 0xB7, 0x2D, 0x82, 0x47, 0x3D, 0xBE, 0x09, 0xF1, 0x1B, 0x55, 0x2A, 0x89, 0x83 };

i try this but dosen't work :

```
    string[] s = File.ReadAllLines("MyFilePath.txt");
List<byte[]> byteArrays = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (string st in s.Where(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("id_number:*=")).Select(x => x.Skip(12)))
{
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)((st.Length + 1) / 2)];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)((st.Length + 1) / 2); i++)
    {
        var byteString = (st.Skip(2 * i).Length > 2) ?  st.Skip(2 * i).Take(2) : "0"+st.Skip(2 * i);
        var bt = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16);
        b[i] = bt;
    }
    byteArrays.Add(b);
}
```

and i dont now where i can put the title ?

please help

Comment: `Skip` returns an `IEnumerable<char>` not a `string`

Answer (score 0):

What selman22 said is correct.

I have made changes to your code to work properly. Here is the working code.

```
string[] s = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\test\test.txt");
var byteArrays = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (string st in s.Where(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("id_number:*=")).Select(x => new string(x.Skip(12).ToArray())))
{
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)((st.Length + 1) / 2)];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)((st.Length + 1) / 2); i++)
    {
        var byteString = ((st.Skip(2 * i).Count() > 2) ? new string(st.Skip(2 * i).Take(2).ToArray()) : "0" + new string(st.Skip(2 * i).ToArray()));
        var bt = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16);
        b[i] = bt;
    }
    byteArrays.Add(b);
}
```